# Get Photoshop Font as TTF

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, truetype-fonts

I recently used photoshop to design a UI mockup for an audio plugin I am developing, only to find that the font I am using is not available on my computer outside of photoshop. I am wondering if there is a way to access the specific font as a TTF in order to incorporate it in my program. If I have to pay for it that is fine, it is well worth the cost to save time.

I am using Helvetica Regular on Sharp setting. The san serif that my operating system defaults to really isn't cutting it, so any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If the font is available in Photoshop, then there's a font file on your system somewhere.

Comment: You can just buy it: https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/helvetica/ But as @Metis says if you can use it in Photoshop then it's on your system. Do you see the Helvetica font file in `C:\windows\fonts`?